# Ruby on rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, web-applications, server-side

If I want to build web application that the server side will be in ruby on rails, I need to learn ruby language in order to that?

I need to mentioned that I am new to ruby and to ruby on rails.
In addition I will be happy for a short explanation what I need to do first in order to do the right steps.

Thanks!!!

Comment: The official ruby guides would be a good place to start: [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: If I understand beyond your word you mean that I need to start learning ruby language before ruby on rails, right?

Comment: The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) are great resources.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Rails" Guides. The getting started guide will direct you to a list of online resources for learning ruby.

Comment: Start from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just started learning Ruby on Rails and according to my experience I started with learning **Rails** using [Micheal Hartl's guidelines book on Ruby on Rails](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). Along with that I learned **Ruby** from [Peter Cooper's Beginning Ruby](http://peterc.org/beginningruby/), this helped me learn both the language and Framework with hand on experience.

This should be good to get started with Ruby on Rails. Other than this there are other really good materials like [Learn Ruby Hard Way](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/). The best way is to start practicing.